# Как в Python получить список шрифтов, которые доступны в системе Windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, шрифты

Как в Python получить список шрифтов, которые доступны в системе Windows?
Аналогичный по составу тому списку, который доступен, например, в MS Word.

**На код**

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import font

root = tkinter.Tk
list_fonts = list(font.families())
```

**python ругается**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"C:/Users/kn/PycharmProjects/test/venv/fonts.py", line 30, in <module>
    list_fonts = list(font.families()) 
    File "C:\Users\kn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\font.py",
line 184, in families
    return root.tk.splitlist(root.tk.call("font", "families", *args))
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tk'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Вместо `root = tkinter.Tk` должно быть`root = tkinter.Tk()`

Comment: Благодарю! Получилось.
`import tkinter
from tkinter import font

root = tkinter.Tk()
list_fonts = list(font.families())`

/Users/kn/PycharmProjects/test1/venv/bin/python /Users/kn/PycharmProjects/test1/venv/1.py

Process finished with exit code 0

Теперь буду искать как вывести этот список на экран )

Comment: import tkinter
from tkinter import font

root = tkinter.Tk()
list_fonts = list(font.families())

print('\n'.join(list_fonts))